# Using nested time series columns as input into function, return value to nested df

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use `ts.union()` to create a column in my nested data frame, with the inputs to `ts.union()` being two nested time series in my nested data frame. See set up below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)
ts_special <- function(df){ts(df,start = c(2010,01), frequency = 4)}
ets_spec <- function(df){ets(df, mod="MMM", opt.crit="lik", damped=NULL)}
x <- cumsum(rnorm(48))
grp <- rep(c("A","B"), 24)
dtf <- cbind(x, grp) %>% data.frame
dtf <- dtf %>% group_by(grp) %>% nest
dtf <- dtf %>%  mutate(ts = map(data, ts_special))
dtf <- dtf %>%  mutate(ets = map(ts, ets_spec))
dtf <- dtf %>%  mutate(ets_fcast = map(ets, forecast))
dtf <- dtf %>%  mutate(pred= map(dtf$ets_fcast, ~ .x[["mean"]]))

# below works but I want to do this the dplyr way and nest this result in a column in dtf
ts.union(dtf$ts[[1]], dtf$pred[[1]])
```

I'd like to have the result of `ts.union` for each group's time series and prediction combination stored in a nested column in my data frame, `dtf`.

Comment: Please make sure your example runs: where is the function `ets` defined?

Comment: thanks @ThomasK, updated. It's the `forecast` package.

Comment: Does `map2` give the expected result, e.g.: `dtf %>% mutate(union = map2(ts, pred, ts.union))`?

Comment: Yes, @ThomasK that's it. Thanks much! Do you want to move your comment to an answer so I can give you credit for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `purrr::map2` to map over the inputs for `ts.union` in parallel:

```
dtf %>% mutate(union = map2(ts, pred, ts.union))
```